# Android fail to create Dagger on project

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

i'm trying to use `Dagger2`on project but i get this error:

```
Error:(42, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerGithubApplicationComponent
```

this implementation work fine into other my project, but i dont know whay after implament that into other project i get this error, i clean project and rebuild again, unfortunately Android Studio dont know whats `DaggerGithubApplicationComponent` on my Application class

[public GitLab Address](https://gitlab.com/tux-world/TestDagger)

**Components**:

```
@ActivitiesScope
@Component(dependencies = GithubApplicationComponent.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activityMain);
}

@AlachiqApplicationScope
@Component(
        modules = {
                NetworkServiceModule.class,
                ActivityModule.class
        }
)
public interface GithubApplicationComponent {
    GithubService getGithubService();
}
```

**Modules**:

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {

    private final Activity context;

    public ActivityModule(Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @AlachiqApplicationScope
    @Named("activity_context")
    public Context context() {
        return context;
    }
}

@Module
public class ContextModule {
    private final Context context;
    public ContextModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }
    @Provides
    @AlachiqApplicationScope
    @ApplicationContext
    public Context context() {
        return context;
    }
}

@Module(includes = ContextModule.class)
public class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @AlachiqApplicationScope
    public HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
            @Override
            public void log(String message) {
                Timber.e(message);
            }
        });
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Provides
    @AlachiqApplicationScope
    public RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxAdapter() {
        return RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io());
    }


    @Provides
    @AlachiqApplicationScope
    public Cache cache(File cacheFile) {
        return new Cache(cacheFile, 10 * 1000 * 1000); //10MB Cahe
    }

    @Provides
    @AlachiqApplicationScope
    public File cacheFile(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
        return new File(context.getCacheDir(), "okhttp_cache");
    }

    @Provides
    @AlachiqApplicationScope
    public OkHttpClient okHttpClient(HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor, Cache cache) {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .cache(cache)
                .build();
    }
}

@Module(includes = NetworkModule.class)
public class NetworkServiceModule {
    private String mBaseUrl;

    public NetworkServiceModule(String baseUrl) {
        mBaseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    @Provides
    @AlachiqApplicationScope
    public GithubService githubService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(GithubService.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @AlachiqApplicationScope
    public Gson gson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, new DateTimeConverter());
        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }

    @Provides
    @AlachiqApplicationScope
    public Retrofit retrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, Gson gson, RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxJavaCallAdapterFactory) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJavaCallAdapterFactory)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Scopes**:

```
@Scope
public @interface ActivitiesScope {
}

@Scope
public @interface AlachiqApplicationScope {
}
```

**Qualifier**:

```
@Qualifier
public @interface ApplicationContext {
}
```

**Application class**:

```
public class APP extends MultiDexApplication {
    public static  String                     packageName;
    public static  Resources                  resources;
    private static Context                    context;
    private static GithubApplicationComponent component;
    private static APP                        instance;
    private        GithubService              githubService;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //@formatter:off
            resources   = this.getResources();
            context     = getApplicationContext();
            packageName = getPackageName();
        //@formatter:on

        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());

        component = DaggerGithubApplicationComponent.builder()
                .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
                .networkServiceModule(new NetworkServiceModule("https://api.github.com/"))
                .build();

        githubService = component.getGithubService();
    }

    public static GithubApplicationComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    public static APP get(Activity activity) {
        return (APP) activity.getApplication();
    }
}
```

I get error for `DaggerGithubApplicationComponent` class into Application class as :

```
component = DaggerGithubApplicationComponent.builder()
        .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
        .networkServiceModule(new NetworkServiceModule("https://api.github.com/"))
        .build();
```

Comment: Just clean and build and import **ir.pishguy.testdagger.Dagger.Components.DaggerGithubApplicationComponent;**. You need dagger to generate code for you. Just ran the app to check for any errors. Works fine

Comment: @Raghunandan i dont get any other error on project, `import ir.pishguy.testdagger.Dagger.Components.DaggerGithubApplicat‌​ionComponent;` dont resolve my problem and `DaggerGithubApplicat‌​ionComponent` is unknown on my project, could you see git repository? Thanks in advance

Comment: i cloned your repo and just did clean and build and i don't see any problem. in fact ran the app on my phone. its fine

Comment: @tux-world did you even try what @Raghunandan said? Let me rephrase that: 1. **Temporarily** comment all `DaggerGithubApplicationComment` stuff. 2. **Temporarily** remove `DaggerGithubApplicationComment` import. 3. Build clean your project. 4. Reverse steps 1. and 2.

Comment: @BartekLipinski i'm wondering what happen !!! i clean,rebuild project and then build project, now i'm expectation to created `DaggerGithubApplicat‌​‌​ionComponent` and can be imported that, i dont have any `import` for that sir

Comment: @tux-world I'm sorry but I can't understand what you mean. Can you try to rephrase that?

Comment: @BartekLipinski yes sure, after clean project and rebuild project android studio must be know whats `DaggerGithubApplicat‌​‌​ionComponent` and after that can be import normally

Comment: @BartekLipinski it seems my Android Studio or Gradle has an error, and it seems my code doesnt have any problem

Comment: @tux-world unless there is some other error (but @Raghunandan said there isn't), after you temporarily remove `DaggerGithubApplicationComponent` and rebuild project -> Android Studio **will** know what it is. If you try to rebuild project **without** temporarily removing `DaggerGithubApplicationComponent` this build will fail and Android Studio won't be able to see this generated code (because it won't be generated).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141942/discussion-between-tux-world-and-bartek-lipinski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion from [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141942/discussion-between-tux-world-and-bartek-lipinski):

2 Issues:

1. There was a warning message showing up for @tux-world:

> Warning: Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing: android-apt. This may result in an unexpected behavior.
> 2. Expected incorrect name of the `Component` class.

---

Solution:

1. Fix `apt` in your project and the missing code will be generated:

a) Gradle plugin `2.2.3`, `android-apt:1.7`, `apt` in your Module build.gradle

b) Gradle plugin `2.3.1`, entirely REMOVED `android-apt`, `annotationProcessor` in your Module `build.gradle`

2. Fix the incorrect name of the generated `Component` class.